# Exclude rows from one table if match on another table - MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables :

the first one called **categories** with 3 columns "administrators,id,name".

```
administrators | id  | name
1              | 23  | David
2              | 24  | Jemmy
3              | 25  | Frank
NULL           | 26  | GLOBAL1
NULL           | 27  | GLOBAL2
NULL           | 28  | GLOBAL3
```

The second table is named **disabledcategories** with two columns "administrators" and "id".

```
administrators | id 
1              | 26  > ( GLOBAL1 )
1              | 27  > ( GLOBAL2 )

2              | 26  > ( GLOBAL1 )
2              | 27  > ( GLOBAL2 )

3              | 26  > ( GLOBAL1 )
3              | 27  > ( GLOBAL2 )
3              | 28  > ( GLOBAL3 )
```

And i want to select "administrators = LIKE 1 OR NULL" from **categories** where there is not in **disabledcategories**

Desired Output like this :

```
administrators | id  | name
1              | 23  | David
NULL           | 28  | GLOBAL3
```

How can i do that ? Thank you so much in advance !

Comment: @Eric i try `select c.* from categories c
where c.administrators = 1
or (
  c.administrators is null
  and 
  not exists (
    select 1 from disabledcategories d
    where d.id = c.id
  )
);` but not working

Comment: @DavidBoe this is not what you tried. This is the code from my answer, right?

Comment: @forpas yes of course, You're about to solve it bro :)

Comment: @DavidBoe you changed 3 times your sample data and expected results and still you did not explain the logic that leads to these results. Why do you want this row: `NULL           | 28  | GLOBAL3` in the results?

Comment: The comments is not the place to explain. Edit your question and put there everything needed to clarify.

Comment: @forpas edited, please solve my probleme

Comment: Your requirement is still not clear after so many edits. If you can't explain what you actually want how do you expect to get a solution? I asked in a previous comment: *Why do you want this row: NULL | 28 | GLOBAL3 in the results?* also why don't you want NULL | 27 | GLOBAL2?

Comment: because administrators 1 have already add 26 and 27 to **disabledcategories**

Comment: @DavidBoe see my edited answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your sample data and expected results I think that this is the query that you want:

```
select c.* from categories c
where c.administrators = 1
or (
  c.administrators is null
  and c.id not in (
    select id from disabledcategories
    where administrators = 1
  )
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vRTZh6cpo6DwVb2EECEBWp/3).
Results:

```
| administrators | id  | name   |
| -------------- | --- | ------ |
| 1              | 23  | David  |
|                | 28  | GLOBAL |
```

Comment: My Output 
`administrators | id | name
1                       | 23 | David `

Comment: @DavidBoe see the demo in my answer.

Comment: sorry check my edit, i want to hide GLOBAL names that already disabled in disabledcategories table

Comment: @DavidBoe the same code works for your new requirement. Check my edited answer.

Comment: in your code you add disabledcategories `VALUES  ('1', '23'), ('2', '24');` try to use `('1', '25'), ('2', '26'), ('2', '27');` because administrators 1 OR 2 can disable any of GLOBAL names

Comment: In my code I use the sample data from your question and the query returns your expected output. *because administrators 1 OR 2 can disable any of GLOBAL names* What is this? Did you mention anything like that in your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select c.*
from categories c
where not exists (select 1
                  from disabledcategories dc
                  where dc.id = c.id
                 ) or
      c.administrators = 1 or
      c.administrators is null;
```

However, for your sample results the lookup is not necessary:

```
select c.*
from categories c
where c.administrators = 1 or
      c.administrators is null;
```

Comment: this query display also other administrators like 2 | 24 | Jemmy

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try LEFT OUTER JOIN without Intersection:

```
SELECT cat.* from categories as cat 
LEFT OUTER JOIN disabledcategories as dicat ON 
    cat.id = discat.id 
WHERE discat.id IS NULL  and (cat.administrator IS NULL OR cat.administrator like '%1%');
```

Hope it will work.